# How does using control variables in experiments affect the bias-variance trade-off?

Tags: experiment-design, control-group, bias-variance-tradeoff

Following up on the post, [Using control variables in experiments?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83277/using-control-variables-in-experiments), I wonder how this connects with the usual bias-variance trade-off? That is, to minimise the MSE one must trade off the gain from adding a control variable in lower bias of the estimate with the loss in higher variance of the estimated coefficient.