Are conditional unbalanced independent variables an issue in regression?
This is a very specific question which is closed for no reason...
Description
I have a dataset with the following characteristics:

Y: balanced binary dependent variable (for example 50% employed/50% unemployed)
X1: balanced binary independent variable (for example 50% treatment/50% control)
X2: a categorical independent variable (for example countries)

X1 is the variable of interest and the goal is to estimate a causal influence of X1 on Y and not a prediction.
A correlation (or a relationship since vaiables ar not metric) between X2 and X1 as well as X2 and Y can be observed.
Issue
If I group X1 by X2 (for example treated and untreated by country), I can observe that the subgroups are not balanced. In some subgroups, close to 100% data is from a certain x1 class (for example the the treated group), in other subgroups close to 100% data is from a different class (for example the untreated group) and in some subgroups the data is 50%/50% balanced regarding x2. In other words, some subgroups are pure.
Question:

Can the conditional subgroup inbalance (or in an extreme case, pureness) be an issue for the x1 coefficient/estimator and its significance from a mathematical point of view? What happens if one conditional subgroup is pure (for example consists of 100% control or treated units)?

Peter Floms answer below hints that this could be a separation problem. However, from my point of view separation is a phenomenon defined as a predictor perfectly splitting/predicting the independent variable. But in this case, there is no variance in a conditional subgroup, but variance in the outcome, so it is not perfectly splitting the dependent variable.

Can you clarify what you mean by "balanced"? It has two definitions: 1) a variable is balanced across the treatment if it is independent of the treatment, 2) a variable is balanced if its proportion is close to .5. You mention treatment, so I'm not sure what you're referring to here. Is this about confounding and causality?

My definition of balanced is that the proportion is close to 0.5

I include X2 because I think it might be a confounder (There is a medium correlation/cramers V relation between X2 and X1 and X2 and Y). That is why I thought of including X2 as "control variable" to get a better estimate of X1's causal effect on Y.

Now, a colleague approached me and mentioned that these kind of "fixed effect" models (since X2 is effectively a dummy) have "inference issues" if the "conditional subgroups" (e.g. X1 grouped by X2) are extremely unbalanced.

He then suggested removing unbalanced subgroups (e.g. countries) with a worse treated-control ratio as 4:1 or 1:4, citing this: https://www.markhw.com/blog/control-size

I think that this is incorrect, but I am not sure. I think unbalanced "conditional subgroups" will be an issue for the power of estimators of the unbalanced subgroups or interaction effects, but not an issue of the magnitude and power of the X1 estimator since X1 estimates the average control/treated effect across subgroups and independent of a specific unbalanced subgroup.

Maybe you should mention if it is an experiment or an observational study. Your use of the word "treatment" hints to an experiment, but the rest of your question does not. If it's observational, arguably it will be quite difficult to make causal inference at all. If it's an experiment, you should mention why the study ended up with no control or treatment in some countries, and why you want to use country as an independent variable. It's possible that you don't have to use the variable "country" at all, but difficult to say without more info about your research question and the study design.

It neither matters if it is an experimental or an observational setting, nor does it matter why one would use the country variable. It could be a city, marriage status or any categorical variable. It is a purely statistical question if pure subgroups can create issues for the coefficients and significant statistics. Closing this question is therefore pretty harsh...

The design does matter for causal inference, because if you're interested in the treatment effect, and if people have been randomly allocated to the treatment , there's an argument that you don't really need to control for the variable "country" (unless there is a specific reason to do so, but you don't mention if there is one, hence it's difficult to suggest anything).

In addition, the question has been closed as lacking focus (i.e. it includes too many questions), which is an additional problem, different from what I'm talking about in my comments above.

I think the problem here boils down to "How should I model the question I'm interested in?", but it's difficult to suggest something if you aren't much more specific. For instance, a possible strategy would be to not use the country name, but instead substituing it for its GDP per capita. Would it be a good idea to do that? It would totally depend on your research question and on the study design.

Now, given your comments, I would have assumed that you're not talking about a randomized trial, but an observational study. However, the fact that you explicitly don't want to be more specific about the study design makes it difficult to give you a comprehensive answer. If someone gives you an answer assuming a randomized trial, it may not apply to a situation where it's in fact an observational study, and vice versa. So it could lead you astray in your analysis.

If it's an experiment/RCT, you might be interested in this other thread: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/83277/164936

It is not about the question "How should I model the question I'm interested in". It is about the question if I model it the way I describe it, and I create pure subgroups by doing so, how are these model decisions and resulting pure subgroups influencing my coefficients and standard errors. The math will be identical independent from the fact that the underlying regression formula is applied to a random experiment or observational study.

OK. About "if I model it the way I describe it,", the thing I was pointing to is that you should consider if modeling it this way is adequate in the first place. XY problems are an extremely frequent thing on this website, that's why I've attempted to get more details, in order to avoid answers that might be misleading or inadequate to solving your actual problem. Note that this is unrelated to the reason why your question has been closed.

The problem you may run into is called separation, this can be complete or partial (aka semi-complete). That happens when some cells are 0 or close to 0. It can, indeed, cause problems. There are various things to do about it. These should be covered in any good book on logistic regression; they are also covered in many papers.  One that I like is a presentation by Paul Allison at SAS Global Forum entitled "Convergence Failures in Logistic Regression". Although this paper will be especially useful if you use SAS, the issues and solutions offered should translate easily to R or whatever.

So thanks for hinting the concept of separtion to me. I found your paper: https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/pdfs/sgf2008/360-2008.pdf
He writes:

"If the problem variable is a dummy variable, then the estimates obtained for the other variables have a special
interpretation. They are the ML estimates for the subsample of cases that fall into the category of the dummy variable
in which observations differ on the dependent variable. "

For example, suppose that the dependent variable is whether
or not a person smokes cigars.  A dummy variable for sex is included in the model, but none of the women smoke
cigars, producing quasi-complete separation."

"If sex is left in the model, the coefficients for the remaining variables
(e.g., age, income, education) represent the effects of those variables among men only.  (This can easily be verified
by actually running the model for men only).  The advantage of doing it in the full sample with sex as a covariate is
that one also gets a test of the sex effect (using the likelihood ratio chi-square) while controlling for the other predictor
variables.  "

Does that mean, that in my case with countries as a dummy variable x1 repesents the influence on the "default" country? Or does it represent the influence across all countries, e.g. after accounting for country effect?

But in general, is this even separation in this case? As far as I understood separation, the definition is, that a dependent variable perfectly splits/predicts Y. But in this case, for one subgroup it is the opposite in my opinion. There is 0 variance in a subgroup while there is variance in the Y for this subgroup. So, my interpretation in this situation would be that it is impossible to estimate the influence of that subgroup, but it should not harm the predictors of other subgroups as well as other coefficients. What do you think?
